# Can you inherit local variables?

Tags: jquery, private, extend, inheritance

I was wondering if the following code is executed, does it inherit local variables from the NewDragDrop function? Does it matter if the NewDragDrop() is the constructor of another class?

```
function NewDragDrop (imageReference, imageTitle){
       var image;
       var title;
}

function InheritDragObject (imageReference, title){

       $.extend(true, this, new NewDragDrop(imageReference, title));
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but you can try this out fairly easily.  Simply execute this code then do something like `var d = new InheritDragObject("ref", "title")` and inspect the result.  Then if you don't understand the result, post a question asking someone to explain it.

Comment: When you use `$.extend` like that, all `NewDragDrop` prototype methods are copied as own properties to the `InheritDragObject` instances, which defeats the purpose of having prototypes (as method containers) in the first place. Either use pseudoclassical inheritance (with functions), or use prototypal inheritance with `Object.create`. The `$.extend` method is not adjusted for inheritance - it serves other purposes.